# simplest tool to measure C program cache hit/miss and cpu time in linux?

Tags: performance, cpu-cache, measurement, context-switch, memcache-stats

I'm writing a small program in C, and I want to measure it's performance.

I want to see how much time do it run in the processor and how many cache hit+misses has it made. Information about context switches and memory usage would be nice to have too.

The program takes less than a second to execute.

I like the information of /proc/[pid]/stat, but I don't know how to see it after the program has died/been killed.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I think Valgrind adds a lot of overhead. That's why I wanted a simple tool, like /proc/[pid]/stat, that is always there.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Use **perf**:

```
perf stat ./yourapp
```

See the [kernel wiki perf tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) for details. This uses the hardware performance counters of your CPU, so the overhead is very small.

Example from the wiki:

```
perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000

Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000':

        5,099 cache-misses             #      0.005 M/sec (scaled from 66.58%)
      235,384 cache-references         #      0.246 M/sec (scaled from 66.56%)
    9,281,660 branch-misses            #      3.858 %     (scaled from 33.50%)
  240,609,766 branches                 #    251.559 M/sec (scaled from 33.66%)
1,403,561,257 instructions             #      0.679 IPC   (scaled from 50.23%)
2,066,201,729 cycles                   #   2160.227 M/sec (scaled from 66.67%)
          217 page-faults              #      0.000 M/sec
            3 CPU-migrations           #      0.000 M/sec
           83 context-switches         #      0.000 M/sec
   956.474238 task-clock-msecs         #      0.999 CPUs

   0.957617512  seconds time elapsed
```

No need to load a kernel module manually, on a modern debian system (with the linux-base package) it should just work. With the `perf record -a` / `perf report` combo you can also do full-system profiling. Any application or library that has debugging symbols will show up with details in the report.

For visualization [flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) seem to work well. (Update 2020: the [hotspot](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot) UI has flame graphs integrated.)

Answer (score 11):

The best tool for you is called **valgrind**. It is capable of memory profiling, call-graph building and much more.

```
sudo apt get install valgrind
valgrind ./yourapp
```

However, to obtain the time your program executed, you can use `time(8)` linux utility.

```
time ./yourapp
```

Comment: can valgrind measure cache, or only principal memory?

Comment: as far as I know, valgrind can measure all cache levels, at least L1 and L2.

Comment: There is a module of Valgrind called cachegrind that measures cache.

Comment: I have no manual for `man 8 time`. What is time(8) is it the C function? I need CPU usage time, not total runtime. And i think Valgrind adds a lot of overhead. That's why I wanted a simple tool, like /proc/[pid]/stat, that is always there.

Comment: It is helpful to note that `/usr/bin/time != time`. In bash, `time` is a built-in shell keyword.

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that cachegrind simulates cache, whereas the perf tool measures from the actual cache.

Comment: `kcachegrind` will mark up your source code to show which lines are causing the misses and spills -- very handy for developers.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
/usr/bin/time -v YourProgram.exe
```

It will show you all this information:

```
/usr/bin/time -v ls
    Command being timed: "ls"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 60%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4080
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 314
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 1
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

You can also use the -f flag to format the output to fit your needs.

Please, be sure to call this program using it's full path, otherway it will call the 'time' command and that's not what you need...

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is helpful to note that `/usr/bin/time != time`. In bash, `time` is a built-in shell keyword.

Comment: But where are the cache misses?

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with cache misses.

Answer (score 8):

**Linux `perf_event_open` system call with `config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS`**

`perf` is likely what OP wants as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114325/895245 but just for completeness, I'm going to show how to do this from inside a C program if you control the source code.

This method can allow for more precise measurements of a specific region of interest within the program. It can also get separate cache hit/miss counts for each different cache level. This syscall likely shares the same backend as `perf`.

This example is basically the same as [Quick way to count number of instructions executed in a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313510/quick-way-to-count-number-of-instructions-executed-in-a-c-program/64863392#64863392) but with `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE`. By doing:

```
man perf_event_open
```

you can see that in this examples we are counting only:

- L1 data cache (`PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D`)
- reads (`PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ`), not writes of prefetches
- misses (`PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS`), not hits

perf_event_open.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <inttypes.h>

static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                    group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    long long count;
    int fd;
    char *chars, c;

    uint64_t n;
    if (argc > 1) {
        n = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        n = 10000;
    }

    chars = malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D |
                PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8 |
                PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    // Don't count hypervisor events.
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Write the memory to ensure misses later. */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        chars[i] = 1;
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    /* Read from memory. */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = chars[i];
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    printf("%lld\n", count);

    close(fd);
    free(chars);
}
```

With this, I get results increasing linearly like:

```
./main.out 100000
# 1565
./main.out 1000000
# 15632
./main.out 10000000
# 156641
```

From this we can estimate a cache line size of: 100000/1565 ~ 63.9 which almost exactly matches the exact value of 64 [according to `getconf LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE`](https://superuser.com/questions/55776/how-to-find-the-l2-cache-size-in-linux) on my computer, so I guess it is working.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 amd64, GCC 9.3.0, Linux kernel 5.4.0, Intel Core i7-7820HQ CPU.

Comment: Operation not supported on my system

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn what's your hardware?

Comment: Beagle Bone black with a yocto distribution ([Some more info here](https://old.reddit.com/r/kernel/comments/18c92ny/why_is_cache_disabled_on_my_system/))

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn OK. Seems to have an ARM Cortex-A8 with ARMv7. Maybe ARMv7 doesn't have support. It would be good to have a quick look at kernel source/docs to undesrtand.

Comment: I am afraid I might get lost trying to dig through the kernel code. Could you give me a couple of concrete pointers inside the kernel sources? That way I can then try to dig further starting from there

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn there isn't much of a science to it, just start googling and grepping until you eigther find the answer or get tired. E.g. this seems of interest: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/ee336b33e40b5eb44f152cda91612313789f9404/arch/arm/kernel/perf_event_v7.c#L160 though I can't immedaitelh match to the flags I provide on the program.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get things working by digging through the kernel code :)
Last question if I may: I have been trying to find a function which allows me to empty (flush/invalidate) the CPU's cache from userspace. Some kernel level implementation I can call from userspace via a syscall somehow. Any idea by any chance? (unrelated to this question, but I really like what you're doing wrt politics. More people should be aware of these things. Keep it up!)

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn oh so there was a missing kernel build config? I think cache flushing is generally available as userland instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277984/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-in-linux-from-a-c-program