# profiling compiler.exe (or an existing executable) on windows

Tags: caching, compilation, profiling

I'm in charge of profiling our compiler/build on windows and I want to get very precise information.
I'm using ProcMon and I'm getting excellent info on all the things that it reports:

1. user, kernel time
2. file, network I/O
3. context switches

[image: ProcMon]

However, I'd also like to know the cache hits/misses.

Unfortunately, ProcMon has no CPU cache counters and Windows' PerfMon only measures 'cache' with respect to RAM, not the CPU cache.

If you're writing a C++ app, it seems there's plenty of resources

[Profiling CPU Cache/Memory from the OS/Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122520/profiling-cpu-cache-memory-from-the-os-application)

Is there a utility in windows, like ProcMon or even Perfmon, that measures the CPU cache hits/misses?