# Object[] with unique instances loops much slower than Object[] filled with identical instance

Tags: java, performance, heap-memory

I am working with array `SomeObject[] someObject = new SomeObject[5000];`.

Each instance inside this array is unique to each other instance but, as a statistical expectation, they require the same computational overhead. In addition the standard deviation of the distribution of computational overhead for each `someObject[i]` is very narrow (each `someObject[i]` should take `8` - `12` nanoseconds each, mostly clustering around `10` nanoseconds).

What I have noticed is that if I fill this array with the identical instance `sharedObject = new SomeObject()`, and loop over `SomeObject[]`, it'll be really fast. For example:

```
 SomeObject sharedObject = new SomeObject();
 for(int i = 0; i < 5000 ; ++i) {
     someObjects[i] = sharedObject;
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < 5000 ; ++i) {
     someObjects[i].doSomething(); //runs really fast.
 }
```

But if I fill the array as:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5000 ; ++i) {
     someObjects[i] =  new SomeObject();
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < 5000 ; ++i) {
     someObjects[i].doSomething(); //runs really slow.
 }
```

then it'll loop over `someObject` 8 times more slowly, even though each instance has the same computational overhead as each other (within 1 or 2 nanoseconds) when isolated.

Why does this occur and how do I stop this explosion of computational cost occurring?

All computations within each instance of `SomeObject` are only over the internal state of that object.

Note that the space on the heap is truly minimal for each `new SomeObject()`, so it is not forcing garbage collection.

Here's some code that recreates the problem (but nowhere near as severe as my real life example):

```
public class Test2 {

    public final double random;
    public final Double[] sub;

    public Test2(double random) {
        this.random = random;

        sub = new Double[1000];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i) {
            sub[i] = Math.random();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i) {
            double j = (i - 1000)*5*6/4/4/4*sub[i];
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 testFirst = new Test2(Math.random());
        Test2[] testFirstArray = new Test2[10000];
        Test2[] testSecondArray = new Test2[10000];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i) {
            testFirstArray[i] = testFirst;
            testSecondArray[i] = new Test2(Math.random());
        }

        //Warmup
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i) {
            testFirstArray[i].doSomething();
            testSecondArray[i].doSomething();
        }

        //Time first class
        double firstTimer = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i) {
            testFirstArray[i].doSomething();
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - firstTimer)/(1000*1000));


        //Time second class
        double secondTimer = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i) {
            testSecondArray[i].doSomething();
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - secondTimer)/(1000*1000));


    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's hard to know what JIT is doing, but since in the first example you process 5000 objects and in the second example a single object 5000 times, there's probably optimizations available. Are you benchmarking things correctly?

Comment: @Kayaman I am using `System.nanoTime()`. I can loop to `1000000` and the same effect happens. What optimizations are there?

Comment: "*even though each instance has the same computational overhead as each other (within 1 or 2 nanoseconds)*" => to measure such short computations, you need to be very carfeful in preparing your micro-benchmark. My guess is that you are not measuring properly.

Comment: @assylias I can scale up a lot and the effect remains (e.g. make the internal computations more rigorous/long) so that each gives 1 us.

Comment: Benchmarking is a sensitive art, so unless you actually know what you're doing, you'll end up with weird results due to things like the JIT kicking in etc. As a guess, at least one of the optimizations happening is that the single object is cached.

Comment: @user2763361 [So many things can go wrong when micro-benchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)... Until you show a complete example that reproduces the behaviour, the answers will only be based on speculation.

Comment: @user2763361 cache locality sounds like a plausible explanation. If you are on linux you can use [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) to check if it is the case. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082517/simplest-tool-to-measure-c-program-cache-hit-miss-and-cpu-time-in-linux

Comment: The `double j =` line in doSomething doesn't do anything. It has no side effects. As a result, the JIT is going to optimize it out. Put the result in an array or something. It may help. If something is faster than it should be, than it's probably not happening at all.

Comment: @allprog it's just an example. My `SomeObject` is different (and proprietary, hence can't post).

Comment: Ok, it's a bad example then. :)

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: @allprog Why does it matter that it doesn't do anything. I recreated the much higher latency.

Comment: This is not a good forum to discuss such questions. You should go ahead and read about the internals of the JVM. It is an incredibly complex piece of software and if you want to benchmark it, you need to do it wisely. Brute force is highly probable to result in unpredictable results. This topic has lots of literature, so you should familiarize yourself with that first.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are doing is know as the [MicroBenchmarks](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/MicroBenchmarks) Since HotSpot

> starts by running your program with an interpreter. When it discovers
>   that some method is "hot" -- that is, executed a lot, either because
>   it is called a lot or because it contains loops that loop a lot -- it
>   sends that method off to be compiled. After that one of two things
>   will happen, either the next time the method is called the compiled
>   version will be invoked (instead of the interpreted version) or the
>   currently long running loop will be replaced, while still running,
>   with the compiled method.

Go through following for [detals](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#benchmarking_simple)

Comment: It doesn't really say how to fix it though

Comment: Doesn't really explain why different parameters give different results

Answer (score 0):

You did not show where you put System.nanoTime(). If the range includes the first loop, then the time to create 5000 new objects is added.

Then, iterating over different objects require loading each object from main memory, while in the first case the same object is taken from the processor cache.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` does not include instantiation. Only the for loop with the `doSomething`.

Comment: How would I test the CPU cache hypothesis?

Comment: declare all fields in SomeObject as volatile, so that they would not be taken from cache, but from the main memory. Both variants should run in roughly the same time.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: No, they'll be taken from the cache anyway. Just the CPU will have to ensure that the cache is in sync with main memory, but this is cheap when not contended. The times will still differ.