# Is there anyway to record the time of cpu cache miss?

Tags: linux, caching, profiling, cpu

I have already tried pref-stat, papi, valgrind.
these tools only extract the number of cache misses for a program.

Is it possible to monitor whole cache and record the time of cache miss or hit?

Comment: Your solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082517/simplest-tool-to-measure-c-program-cache-hit-miss-and-cpu-time-in-linux

Comment: Are you interested in the time *period* (duration) or the *moment* in time (e.g., which access caused the cache miss)?

Comment: Just the time when cache miss occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this:

https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Live_analysis_with_perf_top

And you can print these on the web screen with simple tricks.

Comment: Thanks and Its good, but i need some utility or tool which can get me a very fine grained information of processor i.e. the time stamps of all the cache misses in a given time interval.

Answer (score 1):

In VTune Amplifier [Memory access analysis](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/544170) you can see DRAM bound (due to bandwidth or latency) metric which will give you approximation of cycles affected due to memory problems. You can also see average latency there of memory operations.